# how to use flash media server with android canvas app?

Tags: android, flash, media

I have an android app that uses canvas to draw graphics, chat, video etc.

Can it be possible to store them on FMS (flash media server).

means I just want to know if we can use FMS with android app.

Please suggest....

Thanks